# Why am I getting BOOTMGR is missing error message?

Tags: windows-7, bootmgr

I've got an Asus Eee PC with Windows 7 starter pre-installed on it. Now, I don't have anything attached to it, no CD/USB Stick/Cables. However, I still get this error:

`BOOTMGR is missing`

`Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart`

Since I do not have the USB stick with the windows 7 starter OS and don't want to switch this computer to ubuntu as it is not for me, I can't follow the instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/fixing-bootmgr-is-missing-error-while-trying-to-boot-windows-vista/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely want to try [Super Grub](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/). You can boot from it the same way you would install ubuntu. If you have no external capabilities, you will likely have difficulty fixing this issue.

Comment: SuperGrubDisk's saved me from the same scenario

Comment: Which one should I use for windows 7?

Comment: take a look here: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/WindowsRefusesToBoot